# How do I turn off auto capitalization in macOS El Capitan?

Tags: macos, settings

How do I turn **off** auto capitalization in macOS El Capitan? For certain things I do not want it and it's very annoying. For instance, dictating in a spreadsheet.  In numbers, I cannot select a bunch of fields and lowercase the letters.

Answer (score 3):

System Preferences → Keyboard → Text and disable Capitalize words automatically.

[image]

Comment: ive seen that answer before, but that option does not exist on latest version of el capitan.

Comment: This works in Big Sur.